# Writing matched regex pattern back to input

Tags: c#, regex

So I am using a `List<string> YAMLFileLines = new List<string>();` to store the lines of a text file as following

```
while ((FileLine = r.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    YAMLFileLines.Add(FileLine);
}
```

Now later on I am evaluating each line using a regex pattern as follows:

```
foreach (string Incoming_Line in YAMLFileLines)
{
    string pattern = @"([\#-]+) { prop: ([a-z A-Z _]+), value: ([0-9 a-z A-Z \[ \] \= \"" \, \. \/ ]+) }";
    Match Line_Match = Regex.Match(Incoming_Line, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);

    if (Line_Match.Success)
    {
        string HashValue = Line_Match.Groups[1].Value; // Stpres the   #- or   just   - value
        string VarieName = Line_Match.Groups[2].Value; // Stores the   Srv_Port   paramater
        string VariValue = Line_Match.Groups[3].Value; // Stores the   30000   value

        bool KeepOriginalHash = false; // Force this to false for now

        switch (VarieName)
        {
            case "Srv_Port":
            {
                if (KeepOriginalHash == true)
                {
                    string FileLine = HashValue + " { prop: " + VarieName + ", value: " + textBox_Srv_Port.Text + " }"; // Allow #- or - at start of string
                    WriteFileLines.Add(FileLine);
                }
                else if (KeepOriginalHash == false)
                {
                    string FileLine = "- { prop: " + VarieName + ", value: " + textBox_Srv_Port.Text + " }"; // Remove #- from start of string. All Unlocked
                    WriteFileLines.Add(FileLine);
                }

                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I am doing is creating a switch case for one of the matching groups which matches the variable name in the text file. I then want to use a textBox.Text on a form to put the value into the line and write it back to a  new List `WriteFileLines.Add(FileLine);` Now my example does work sort of however the problem is that I have to specify exactly what is to be written back to the new list so for example this line `- { prop: " + VarieName + ", value: " + textBox_Srv_Port.Text + " }` would end up as `-" { prop: Srv_Port, value: 30000 }` in the `List<string> WriteFileLines = new List<string>();` The problem with this is that it removes the comments from the line in the incoming text file line which could look like this `-" { prop: Srv_Port, value: 52386 } #Recommended port range between 49152 - 65535` I do not want to loose anything in any of the read in file lines. I just want to match a pattern with the 3 groups and then change the value of one of the groups and write the whole line again to a new List.

To summarise. I want to read a text file line by line into a List object. An example text file line is

```
- { prop: Srv_Port, value: 52386 } #Recommended port range between 49152 - 65535
```

I want to match 3 groups change the value of one of the groups based on the status of the other groups then write the entire line that was read in back to a new List object.

I have looked at regex.Replace however in all the examples I have seen it only seems to give you the result of a pattern replacement. And not the entire line with the changes.

Comment: Append another subpattern `(.*)` at the end of your regex, and it will be your `Line_Match.Groups[4].Value` that you will append to each modified line.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew would you be able to give an example I am struggling to grasp how to implement it.

Comment: Try [`([#-]+)\s*{\s*prop:\s*([a-zA-Z_]+),\s*value:\s*([0-9a-zA-Z[\]="",./]+) }(.*)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%5b%23-%5d%2b)%5cs*%7b%5cs*prop%3a%5cs*(%5ba-zA-Z_%5d%2b)%2c%5cs*value%3a%5cs*(%5b0-9a-zA-Z%5b%5c%5d%3d%22%22%2c.%2f%5d%2b)+%7d(.*)&i=-+%7b+prop%3a+Srv_Port%2c+value%3a+52386+%7d+%23Recommended+port+range+between+49152+-+65535).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I had completely misunderstood what you meant. However, The whole idea of using an additional matching group to capture the rest of the line regardless of its content never came to mind.   I am going to try and implement and see how it functions. Thanks for the input so far.

Comment: @RyanWalkowski Hey there! Were you able to find a working solution?